# How to solve ambiguity caused by function overloading like this?

Tags: c++, literals, overloading, ambiguous-call

I have a piece of code similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Class
{
public:
    Class() {}
    void foo(T)  {cout << "foo(T) is called \n";}
    void foo(T&) {cout << "foo(T&) is called \n";}
};

int main()
{
    Class<int> c;
    int a = 1;

    c.foo(1);
    c.foo(a);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to have both overloads of function `foo` because `foo(T&)` is more efficient but I can't use a literal constant as it's argument and `foo(T)` will work for literal constants although it is not as efficient as `foo(T&)`. But when I define both functions there will be an ambiguous call when `c.foo(a)` is going to execute.

> error: call of overloaded 'foo(int&)' is ambiguous

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Use one function `void foo(const T&)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass by const reference `const T&` so that it will also accept literal constants, or pass by rvalue reference `T&&` instead of `T` so that it will only accept rvalues (like literal constants)